# input data to editText OR display results in the same field

Tags: java, android, xml

I am doing a loan payment calculator. I want to allow the activity to have the following be required:

Rate and Balance

I want the following to be optional

Monthly Payment or Term length

depending on which of the optional ones are selected, I want the "Calculate" button to determine the other one. I can get the math, but I am unsure how to allow an editText field to display a variable if previously unused.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".New_Debt" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/debtor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Debtor*" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDebtor"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/debtor"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/balance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/debtor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/debtor"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Balance*" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editBalance"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/balance"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/balance"
    android:layout_below="@+id/balance"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Rate (APR)*" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editRate"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/term"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Term" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTerm"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/term"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/payment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/term"
    android:layout_below="@+id/term"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Monthly Payment" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPayment"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/payment"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/additionalPayment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/payment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/payment"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Additional Payment" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPayment"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/additionalPayment"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
    android:text="Calculate" />
```

Comment: So your question is: "how to allow an editText field to display a variable if previously unused" ?

Comment: I'm in the process of learning the code now, that's where I'm getting hooked. I have the layout of the fields and descriptive text for them. I'm building the math for an onclick. Once clicked, I'm looking for how to determine which of the 2 fields was blank, and display the answer based on the equation used.

Comment: ok can you share your layout as well? it will explain the question even more and also the code

Comment: see edit for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine which Edittext is blank use

```
if (myEditText.getText().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .setText(String) method on your editText. Then use an 'if' 'else' statement for the logic component if the editText is anything other than what you have it set at by the setText(). You can use the getText() method to retrieve what the user typed in.

Also look at the tutorial of a loan calculator: http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/loancalculator-phase-1-iteration-1.html